# How do I print a column matrix?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to print out the contents of a column matrix in Haskell:

```
data Vector n e where
    Nil :: Vector Zero e
    (:>) :: e -> Vector n e -> Vector (Succ n) e

infixr :>

data Matrix r c e where
    ColMatrix :: Vector r e -> Matrix r One e
    (:|) :: Vector r e -> Matrix r c e -> Matrix r (Succ c) e

infixr :|

instance Show e => Show (Matrix r c e) where
    show (ColMatrix v) = -- ...
    show (v :| m)      = -- ...
```

I'm not sure how to implement this, though. The logical progression is to go

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

but printing to the terminal doesn't make this especially easy.

How do I implement this instance of `Show` for a `ColMatrix`?

Comment: There are really two questions here....  How do you do the Haskell stuff (ie- create instances of Vector that iterate through the values, etc), and how do you do the formatting of the output (ie- fill in all the whitespace properly to get evenly spaced columns).  Which aspect are you more insterested in?  The latter is a bit of a pain to deal with, because you have to pre-iterate over all the values to get the column widths, then run through it again to actually output the text....

Comment: @jamshidh Honestly, I didn't even consider the columns not lining up when the elements are of different lengths... For now, I'm mostly interested in the former. The alignment stuff I can probably figure out later / on my own when the time comes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider something like Brent Yorgey's [boxes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/boxes) package, whose maintenance I recently took over. Use `text` to put each number in a box, use `//` to build the columns, and then use `<+>` to put the columns together into a matrix. Then `render` the result. You can use `cols` to compare the widths of the columns before pasting them together so you can pad them all to the same width, if you like.

Please note that `Show` is *not* for pretty printing. It is intended for human-readable serialization to a Haskell-like format.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses ordinary lists and list library functions.

```
toList :: Vector n e -> [e]
toList Nil = []
toList (a :> v) = a : toList v

instance Show e => Show (Matrix r c e) where
    show (ColMatrix v) = concat $ intersperse " "  (map show  (toList v))
    show (v :| m)      = show (ColMatrix v) ++ "\n" ++ show m
```